# web api service dies randomly without throwing an exception?

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, ldap

I have a Web API 2.2 service which retrieves group-user membership for different AD domains and appends this info to a List>.

The service successfully processes about 10k associations for corp-domain-1 but when attempting to process approx the same amount of associations for corp-domain-2, the API basically just dies without throwing an exception.  Meaning that my localhost browser simply exits out and I don't see any additional info in the event logs off-hand.

The API does not have any type of custom exit logic that could potentially get triggered. This behavior happens consistently for corp-domain-2. Have you ever experienced this type of behavior with a Web API service?  Any idea what the issue might be or how to debug?

Comment: no if you're running web api on iisexpress then you'll need to load the api/help page which will host the service, then you can submit a request to it from a local postman instance.  the browser will normally stay open between requests but there's something weird with this one particular domain that shuts down the browser and terminates the process.  this weird behavior only happens with one particular domain

Answer (score 0):

I think this was due to a StackOverflow exception which can sometimes have different behavior than other exceptions.  I added some logging and I added code to skip the record that I suspected had the problem and now the api call completes as expected